# Dar permiso para poder ver las imágenes en una carpeta específica vía .htaccess, error 403

Tags: .htaccess, seguridad

Tengo una carpeta `/img` y dentro de ella tengo imágenes que quiero mostrar y/o enviar en mensajes de email. Probando una plantilla de email intento usar una de esas imágenes y no se muestra. En el inspector tengo el error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403
> (Forbidden)

He intentando esto en el `.htaccess` de la carpeta `/img`, pero no funciona:

```
<Files ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
   order deny,allow
   allow from all
</Files>
```

Intenté también esto en la carpeta root, pero cuando pongo esa regla da error en todo el dominio, supongo que es porque estoy en un **hosting compartido** ¿?

```
<Directory "img/">
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**¿Cómo podría autorizar las imágenes que tengo en  `/img`?**

Comment: Hola @Marcos, no me admite directivas del tipo `Directory`, no sé si es porque estoy en hosting compartido y mis permisos son limitados. Si pongo eso el sitio no funciona y marca el error *The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.*

Comment: @Marcos el directorio tiene permisos `755`, por lo que no tiene restricción de lectura al público en cuanto directorio. En mi sitio tengo Wordpress y dentro del `.htaccess` del root hay reglas al respecto, pero esto quiero hacerlo independiente de Wordpress. Puede que sea alguna de esas reglas de WP, no sé. Si pongo la carpeta en `uploads` de WP tampoco funciona. Pero si subo el archivo desde WP entonces funciona, pero en otra carpeta, de las de WP, pero no quiero eso.

Comment: @Marcos es el mismo dominio, por lo que no debería haber problema de hotlinking.